# Can Databricks Pools be used across different workspaces?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Let's say I want to create a pool but this pool has to be shared across different Databricks Workspaces.

Is it possible to implement this? If yes, it would be great if could direct me to the right resources!

I have tried creating pools for 1 workspace but I am not sure how I can extend the same pool to multiple Databricks workspaces.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible - the instance pool is defined only inside a specific workspace, and will be accessible for jobs/clusters/DLT pipelines only inside that workspace.